# Why and when construct to copy object?

Tags: c#

I am new to programming with C#, and I saw an example in one of textbooks that I read.

This example is about abstract class explanation, but I did not understand one part of the code :

```
// Create an abstract class.
using System;
abstract class TwoDShape
{
    double pri_width;
    double pri_height;
    // A default constructor.
    public TwoDShape()
    {
        Width = Height = 0.0;
        name = "null";
    }
    // Parameterized constructor.
    public TwoDShape(double w, double h, string n)
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
        name = n;
    }
    // Construct object with equal width and height.
    public TwoDShape(double x, string n)
    {
        Width = Height = x;
        name = n;
    }
    // Construct a copy of a TwoDShape object.
    public TwoDShape(TwoDShape ob)
    {
        Width = ob.Width;
        Height = ob.Height;
        name = ob.name;
    }
}
```

Why and when I construct a copy of object this case?

Comment: Please take the time to make the posted code readable

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

when you class is an abstract class, you cannot construct an object with it. You need to do an heritage on an other class. Here you can do a rectangle class herite of the TwoDShape like this:

```
    using System;

abstract class TwoDShape
{
    double pri_width;
    double pri_height;
    // A default constructor.
    public TwoDShape()
    {
        Width = Height = 0.0;
        name = "null";
    }
    // Parameterized constructor.
    public TwoDShape(double w, double h, string n)
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
        name = n;
    }
    // Construct object with equal width and height.
    public TwoDShape(double x, string n)
    {
        Width = Height = x;
        name = n;
    }
    // Construct a copy of a TwoDShape object.
    public TwoDShape(TwoDShape ob)
    {
        Width = ob.Width;
        Height = ob.Height;
        name = ob.name;
    }
}
Class Rectangle:TwoDShape
{
public Rectangle(double w, double h) : base(w, h)
{
}
}
```